# shouldComponentUpdate not firing after a Redux dispach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### I have a component with a situation like this:

1. Fetch data from the server and update the page's *reducer* with **`status`** of
   `pending`, `success` or `fail` via a dispatch.
2. `mapStateToProps` does include the page **`status`** from the page's *reducer*, which can be verified since the **`status`** key is present in `this.props`.
3. I expect `shouldComponentUpdate` to fire once I get a `fail` status dispatched, but it does **not** get invoked, and my app is simply stuck in a "between" state, and cannot trigger a render because it depends on `shouldComponentUpdate` to fire and tell it to render if the **`status`** is anything except `pending`.

I've noticed that `shouldComponentUpdate` gets sometimes fired after a few dispatches, like it's waiting for them to accumulate or something, not sure..

---

Does anybody know why `shouldComponentUpdate` isn't automatically triggered after my final dispatch when the `fail` status was dispatched?

Comment: Can you show any code?

Comment: I didn't want to post the code because I was certain it was something in my *specific* code, since a simplified test I've created did not reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was the problem; inside `shouldComponentUpdate` I wrote:

```
return this.props.status != 'pending';
```

Since I thought that the lifecycle after Redux made a change to the state would reflect in `this.props` but what I really should have been doing is using `nextProps.status`, because `nextProps` is exposed as `shouldComponentUpdate` argument:

```
shouldComponentUpdate( nextProps, nextState ){
   return nextProps.status.status != 'pending';
}
```

---

The idea behind all this is to not trigger a ton of `render` calls since my store has many dispatches from data fetches in the background until all data needed is received, and each `dispatch` updated the `props` therefor the `render` method was called many times, and I did (still do) not trust React to not actually re-render the DOM if no changes were actually made should reflect in the DOM change, but nevertheless, `render` was fired.

I am a bit new to react, and I do not understand why does `render` get fired when the state changed but the render's `JSX` doesn't care about those specific changes..